# Highlight context menu row with different color in ag grid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ag-grid

[Context Menu Row with different color - the last Row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KZ1D.png)

I have selected 4 Row but its not clear that which Row value contains the Context Menu as all are highlighted in same color, so I want 4th Row to be highlighted in different color.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be highlight the hovered on row with a different color using css as below described in this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#highlighting-rows-and-columns)-

```
.ag-row-hover {
  /* putting in !important so it overrides the theme's styling as it hovers the row also */
  background-color: #dfdfff !important;
}
```

A slightly more elaborate approach would involve listening to when the context menu event is emitted and highlighting that particular row with a different row style.

Comment: This wont work in my case. I am adding the feature to update selected Row with the row where context Menu is clicked and need this to distinguish to selected Row and contetx menu row. Any idea how to highlight row with any color when you know row index

Comment: Thanks for replying.
It worked with this -

`ag-theme-alpine .ag-ltr .ag-row-focus 
{ 
border: 1px solid red; background-color: lightblue;
 } 
`